# Display content on website only when user likes a certain page

Tags: facebook

I'm administrator of a Facebook page and would like to show a message to people who liked my page when they visit my domain.

I can find some tutorials on how to do it as a page-tab but I want to show it on my website. 
How can I get this to work? I've scanned https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ but I don't know where to start?

I've made an application and have an app-id and app secret.... But then......

Could anyone point me in the good direction?

---

Thank you for the answers but I'm guessing I'm not clear in what i want. What I don not need is : a way to register the click on the like button.

What I do want is the following:
A user liked my Facebook page and then visits my website. On my website I want to display a message to the user, e.g.: "You liked us on Facebook! Well done" In the future we want to show the user a coupon code for a free beer or something else.

Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing you use javascript since you wrote "when they visit my domain."
I dug this code up from one of my old projects:

```
// load fb
// don't load if already loaded
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
if(document.getElementById(id)){
    return;
}

js = document.createElement('script');
js.id = id;
js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);

// when fb has loaded, initialize and add some listeners
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: null, status: true, cookie:true, xfbml:true, trace:true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(h, widget) {
        // h = liked link
            // do something eg show message or save state via js cookie or ajax php call
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(h, widget) {
        // h = unliked link
            // do something ag hide message or save state via js cookie or ajax php call
    });
};
```

This is actually a modification of the facebook javascript API loading script.

Comment: OK But where can I indicate from which page the like-status should be got from?

Comment: umm.. I Don't quite understand what you're looking for. document.location is where the user's browser is at, you could compare that with what you want in an if statement, or you can see in the code I posted, the `h` variable contains the href, the 'target' of the like.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. Please take a look at my edited OP

Comment: oh.. I'm sorry, I don't think that's possible. Only if they use a like button on your site :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event listener. It basically 'watches' the like button and 'snitches' when someone clicks on it

Add this somewhere in the head of your document

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' });

 });
</script>
```

Now we add the snitch

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
 alert('You just liked the stUrbs URL '+href);


 });
 //Add the comment snitch here if you need it. Shown below
 };
```

You can go further and snitch when someone adds a comment:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(href, widget) {
alert('You just commented on stUrbs URL '+href);


 });
```

Naturally, you'll want to do something more elegant than alerts